# Which function to execute grant or synonyms?

Tags: r, rjdbc

I have a synonym statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM  sample-table-name FOR master.sample-table-name
```

I want to execute this by using R language using RJDBC library. I've tried different functions including dbGetQuery function etc. But it is not able to execute this statement.

Could someone please advise on how to execute these statements in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect that using `dbExecute()` should work. Failing that, `dbSendStatement()` should almost certainly work, as it seems to be intended for that sort of DDL.

The docs on `dbGetQuery` say:

> This method is for SELECT queries only

To look at the functions that are available to you, it can be helpful to do something like `ls('package:DBI')`.  Per the docs:

`dbExecute`:

> Executes a statement and returns the number of rows affected.
>   dbExecute() comes with a default implementation (which should work
>   with most backends) that calls dbSendStatement(), then
>   dbGetRowsAffected(), ensuring that the result is always free-d by
>   dbClearResult().

`dbSendStatement`:

> The dbSendStatement() method only submits and synchronously executes
>   the SQL data manipulation statement (e.g., UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT
>   INTO, DROP TABLE, ...) to the database engine. To query the number of
>   affected rows, call dbGetRowsAffected() on the returned result object.
>   You must also call dbClearResult() after that. For interactive use,
>   you should almost always prefer dbExecute().

**EDIT:** Those methods will likely work for other implementations of `DBI`, and perhaps for `RJDBC` in the future.  In any case, it looks like they have implemented `dbSendStatement()` using `dbSendQuery()`, so they will not work for this purpose.

In the `RJDBC` framework, `dbSendUpdate()` is what you want.

> dbSendQuery and dbSendUpdate submit a SQL query to the database. The
>   difference between the two is only that dbSendUpdate is used with DBML
>   queries and thus doesn't return any result set.

Confirmed using a similar query on another DBMS:

```
dbSendStatement(conn,'SET search_path=public;')
#Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
#Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for SET search_path=public; (No results were returned by the query.)

traceback()
#7: stop(..., " (", .jcall(x, "S", "getMessage"), ")")
#6: .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ", 
#       statement)
#5: .local(conn, statement, ...)
#4: dbSendQuery(conn, statement, ...)
#3: dbSendQuery(conn, statement, ...)                ## this is the problem
#2: dbSendStatement(conn, "SET search_path=public;")
#1: dbSendStatement(conn, "SET search_path=public;")

dbSendUpdate(conn, 'SET search_path=public;')
# successful

dbCommit(conn)
# persist the change past the current session (RJDBC seems to give you transaction control here)
```

Comment: dbExecute or dbSendStatement didn't work. Any other working alternative. These grants and synonyms come under the oracle objects. So to execute these objects there should be some other function in R

Comment: Any info on the error messages you received when they did not work?

Comment: Error in .verify.JDBC.result(md, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set meta data for ",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set meta data for CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM  sample-table-name FOR master.sample-table-

name in dbSendQuery (ORA-01003: no statement parsed

The executed statement is : outputrecord<-dbExecute(jdbcConnection,runquery);

But even then in the error it is showing dbSendQuery..

Comment: Ok, I am not super familiar with `RJDBC`, but it looks like they may have implemented `dbSendUpdate()` - have you tried that yet?

Comment: DbSendUpdate didn't throw any error but the return value was NULL and the operation didn't happen.

Comment: This may be silly... I don't think you need a semicolon, but it couldn't hurt. Other options: (1) Try some other database statements (CREATE TABLE, etc.).  (2) Try executing `SELECT` statements within the same session (from R), to see if the DBML is being executed for the session but not persisted.  (3) Try executing `dbCommit` afterwards.  Also, we expect a NULL return value.

Comment: Yes dbCommit helped it. Thanks a lot. @C.Arendt